# Bigquery views take too much space in the google deployment manager yaml, any way to use sql files?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-deployment-manager

Problem:

Our bigquery views take too much space in the google deployment manager yaml, resulting that our deployment-manager.yaml file exceeds 1MB:

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/quotas

Question:

Is there a way to insert sql files into the string field in the deployment manager from a bucket or git repository?

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/1c594e5c195427a57016484a0e6b374e32207101/community/cloud-foundation/templates/bigquery/bigquery_table.py.schema#L90

```
view:
type: object
description: The view definition.
properties:
  query:
    type: string
    description: |
    The query that BigQuery executes when the view is referenced.
```

We currently are exploring these options:

1: adapt  the deployment manager yaml to use sql files

2: take out the bigquery views from the deployment manager and create custom CI/CD build scripts

Are there any other ideas to use the deployment manager for a lot of views with long sql statements? or other suggestions? to convert the whole project to terraform for example would take a lot of effort.